# iOS7 warning when submit to the App Store

Tags: ios7, app-store, locale

I get this error/warning about unrecognized locale when submitting an iOS7 project to the App Store, the project is based on a iOS6 project so I assume there is some change on iOS7 when submitting.

Any clue to fix this?

[image: iOS7 Warning]

Comment: Please type the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed by removing a NULL locale directory "ua.lproj" from the Appirater library and reference again.

Answer (score 2):

There's another possibility. In our app we use a fake locale (yy) that helps us with translations. When we submit the app we have the same problem as above but we don't want the yy.lproj/ folder deleted.

Our solution is based on the `EXCLUDED_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES` user defined build setting. Under a target's 'build settings' tab we add a new entry with the value `yy.lproj/*`. This will prevent all files from that fake locale to be included, removing the warning and slimming the app.

[image]

**Update for Xcode 9.1:**

It seems this is now a pre-defined build setting. Under the target's *Build Settings* tab, I typed `exclude` into the search box, and it showed an empty setting *Excluded Source File Names*.  I was able to double click on the right, tap "+" at the bottom of the box that appeared and then add the filename path.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this is very useful!